# Open an auto generated table view when a cell inside an auto generated table is pressed (Swift 2.0, Xcode 7)

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I have currently been able to auto generate a table from core data.

I need to be able to set it up so that when one of cells is pressed it will open a table view. Both of them will be generated from core data, I have set them out in core data with the proper relations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new TableViewController and when you select a cell, navigate to new it.